# Convert groovy string to map in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm fairly new to Groovy and Jenkins pipelines and i need a string converted to a map to get some workable data i haven't been able to find a solution so far.

```
[fileListJs:file1.js,file2.js,file3.js, fileListHtml:file4.html,file5.html,file6.html, fileListCss:file6.css,file7.css,file8.html]
```

The string above is what a certain jenkins choice parameter is returning me in a groovy variable. Now i need this to be a proper map to be able to parse the data in there.

So i tries this approach:
[Groovy String To map](https://dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-turn-a-map-or-list-as-string-to-ma)

Which does the following code:

```
def fileMap =
    // Take the String value between
    // the [ and ] brackets.
    fileList[1..-2]
        // Split on , to get a List.
        .split(', ')
        // Each list item is transformed
        // to a Map entry with key/value.
        .collectEntries { entry ->
            def pair = entry.split(':')
            [(pair.first()): pair.last()]
        }
```

Where fileList is the variable that has returned the previous given string.

But this is not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
String fileList = "[fileListJs:file1.js,file2.js,file3.js, fileListHtml:file4.html,file5.html,file6.html, fileListCss:file6.css,file7.css,file8.css]"

fileList[1..-2]
       .split(/, /)
       *.tokenize(/:/)
       .collectEntries { [ it[0], it[1].tokenize(/,/) ] }
```

should give a result Map as

```
[
  fileListJs:  ['file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js'], 
  fileListHtml:['file4.html', 'file5.html', 'file6.html'], 
  fileListCss: ['file6.css', 'file7.css', 'file8.css']
]
```

Comment: Okay i don't think i fully understand this, what is assert? And does this mean i have to write out that array static like that? Sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: Oh sorry for my ignorance. assert is a way to run assertions in groovy. I am going to update the answer little bit verbosely. Makes sense?

Comment: Yes this 100% makes sense go to test this out right now, will report back in a few! Thanks a lot!

Comment: getting an error in jenkins saying the star-dot operator is not yet supported :-| any way i can write this without that operator?

Comment: You might be using a very old version of Groovy. But yes, there is a way around for that. Instead of `*.tokenize(/:/)` you can use `.collect { it.tokenize(/:/) }`

Comment: Thanks that did it!