# Convert this typical string to map in jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have this typical map(dictionary) string and needs to convert to dictionary in jenkins.

```
[
prDetails:[
    [prInfo:[pull_request:https://github.com/kiek/nanny-test3/pull/17, organization:kiek, repository:nanny-test3, pr_number:17], authors:[abc@dmc.com]],
    [prInfo:[pull_request:https://github.com/kiek/nanny-test3/pull/18, organization:kiek, repository:nanny-test3, pr_number:18], authors:[kis@dmc.com,crc@dmc.com]] 
],
authors:[abc@dmc.com,crc@dmc.com,kis@dmc.com], 
buildCause:BranchEventCause
]
```

Taken this as an example [Convert groovy string to map in jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49785879/convert-groovy-string-to-map-in-jenkins-pipeline) but couldn't find a proper solution. Can someone help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Map converted to string is not a typical use case. Can't you use some common standard, like JSON to serialize map to JSON on one end, and then deserialize the JSON to map without any issues? Trying to reconstruct a map object from something that looks like `map.toString()` is considered as a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: "Trying to reconstruct a map object from something that looks like map.toString() is considered as a bad practice and should be avoided." - not only that, you should never ever do it. toString is not even good for debugging (see .inspect and .dump instead). Using a format that is capable of doing a basic ser-de can not be stressed enough.

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward solution would be to use Groovy's `eval` functionality.

The problem is, that the input shall be prepared for it: you need to insert quotes at right places.

Hence the code:

```
def a = '''[
  prDetails:[
      [prInfo:[pull_request:https://github.com/kiek/nanny-test3/pull/17, organization:kiek, repository:nanny-test3, pr_number:17], authors:[abc@dmc.com]],
      [prInfo:[pull_request:https://github.com/kiek/nanny-test3/pull/18, organization:kiek, repository:nanny-test3, pr_number:18], authors:[kis@dmc.com,crc@dmc.com]]
  ],
  authors:[abc@dmc.com,crc@dmc.com,kis@dmc.com],
  buildCause:BranchEventCause
  ]'''


a = a.replaceAll( /:([^,\[\]\n]+)/, ':"$1"' ) // add " to map's values
a = a.replaceAll( /\[([^:\[\]]+)\]/, '["$1"]' ) // add " inside arrays
a = a.replaceAll( /(\w),(\w)/, '$1","$2' ) // add " around ,

Map map = Eval.me a

assert map.prDetails[0].authors[0] == 'abc@dmc.com'
```